# sum function using subquery

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql

I have three tables:

**Customer**

```
customer_id   first_name
1              kapil
2              rajesh
```

**Account**

```
Customer_id     Account_id
1                   S1
2                   s2
```

**Receipt**

```
Recipt_id   customer_id   Account_id   Transaction_type   Amount
R1            1              s1         Deposit           40000
R2            2              s2         Deposit             300
R3            1              s1         withdrawal         2000
```

now i am putting query as follow

```sql
select   
    c.customer_id,c.first_name,s.current_balance,s.account_id,
    (select sum(amount) 
    from receipt as r ,
        saving_account as s 
    where r.transaction_type='deposit'
        and r.account_no = s.account_id
    ) as debit,
    (select sum(amount) 
    from receipt as r ,
        saving_account as s
    where r.transaction_type='withdrawl'
        and r.account_no = s.account_id  
    )as credit 
from customer as c 
left outer join saving_account as s 
inner join receipt as r on r.customer_id = s.customer_id 
on s.customer_id = c.customer_id 
group by c.customer_id
```

but it is giving me debit a single value for whole row and credit tooo
i am not understanding why it is showing like that ....

My desired result is:

```
customer_id customer_name account_id debit credit balance
1           kapil         s1         40000   2000  200
2           rajesh        s2         300     null  500
```

Comment: what should then be your desired result?

Comment: There's no correlation between the sub selects and the customer

Comment: there is no need of customer table because customer table is just storing the id

Comment: That isn't what correlation means

Comment: @Ashishsingh can you my answer below? hope it's the one you are looking :)

Comment: You could run your sub select in isolation, so it will produce the same result regardless of what customer the outer query is currently looking at. You could fix this by including s.customer_id = c.customer_id in the inner queries correlating the outer customer value with the inner select. (You might also need to add r.customer_id = s.customer_id)

Comment: MAN, first learn the basics of `GROUP BY` clause!!!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try this:

```
select
  c.customer_id, 
  c.first_name,
  a.account_id,
  sum(case 
        when r.transaction_type='deposit' then r.Amount 
        else 0 
      end) as Debit,
  sum(case 
        when r.transaction_type='withdrawal' then r.Amount 
        else 0 
      end) as Credit,

  sum(case 
        when r.transaction_type='deposit' then r.Amount 
        else 0 
      end)-
  sum(case 
        when r.transaction_type='withdrawal' then r.Amount 
        else 0 
      end) as balance
from customer c
join account a
  on c.customer_id = a.customer_id
join Receipt r
  on a.account_id = r.account_id
group by 
  c.customer_id, 
  c.first_name,
  a.account_id
```

**You can also [test it online](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e476f/9).**

**Note:** I did not know how to determine `Balace`, so I just computed it by `Debit - Credit`.

Answer (score 5):

```
SELECT  customer_ID, first_name, Account_ID,
        Deposit, Withdrawal, 
        (Deposit - Withdrawal) balance
FROM 
(
    SELECT  a.customer_ID, 
            a.first_name,
            b.Account_ID,
            SUM (CASE WHEN c.transaction_type = 'Deposit' THEN c.Amount ELSE 0 END) Deposit,
            SUM (CASE WHEN c.transaction_type = 'withdrawal' THEN c.Amount ELSE 0 END) Withdrawal
    FROM    customer a
            INNER JOIN Account b
                ON a.customer_ID = b.customer_ID
            LEFT JOIN Receipt c
                ON b.customer_ID = c.customer_ID AND
                    b.account_ID = c.Account_ID
    GROUP BY a.customer_ID, a.first_name, b.Account_ID
) bb
```

- [**SQLFiddle Demo**](http://www.sqlfiddle.com/#!3/e476f/10)

Answer (score 1):

Inferring the current_balance column on the saving_account table:

```
Select
  c.customer_id,
  c.customer_name,
  s.account_id,
  sum(case when r.transaction_type = 'Deposit' Then r.Amount Else 0 End) As debit,
  sum(case when r.transaction_type = 'Withdrawal' Then r.Amount Else 0 End) as credit,
  s.current_balance
From
  customer c
    left outer join
  saving_account s
    on c.customer_id = s.customer_id
    left outer join
  receipt r
    on s.customer_id = r.customer_id and s.account_id = r.account_id
Group By
  c.customer_id,
  c.customer_name,
  s.account_id,
  s.current_balance
```